# Merge and create an unique case sensitive array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, underscore.js

It's a complicated scenario but will try to explain as much as possible. I have one object or arrays and one array. Now i have to compare selectedmodel values with mappedmodels, if the value(Case insensitive) matches with that object then fetch all the values of it and push it into selected model and combine both.  Hope the example will clear what i am trying to achive.

```
var mappedModels = { 'CC605': ['cc605', 'CC605', 'cC605'], 'TC75X': ['TC75X'] };
var selectedModels = ['CC605', 'tc76'];
var desiredOutput = ["CC605", "tc76", "cc605", "cC605"];
```

I already wrote a solution to achieve it but i need a better code in terms of performance. Here is the solution:

```
function combineModelCases(selectedModels) {
const modelCases = [];
selectedModels.forEach(elm => {
  const existingModels = mappedModels[elm.toUpperCase()];
  if (existingModels) {
    for (const key of existingModels) {
      if (elm.toUpperCase() !== key) {
        modelCases.push(key);
      }
    }
  }
});
return selectedModels.concat(modelCases);
```

}

Here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mf9xvneb/)

I am using typescript and underscore js for your references. Any help would be very helpful.

Comment: It looks fine to me, there's no unnecessary computational complexity (though I guess you could call `elm.toUpperCase` just once, instead of multiple times). The code could be trimmed down a bit, but that wouldn't necessarily do anything (positive or negative) for performance. If you're having performance issues, I bet this isn't the main bottleneck to focus on

Comment: Will the keys of `mappedModels` always be in uppercase? And, are you doing `elm.toUpperCase() !== key` to avoid duplicates?

Comment: @adiga, Yes that's right. Always will be in uppercase and that to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get a flattened array of values for each key in `selectedModels`. Then, create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get a unique collection models. Use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the set to an array.

```js
const mappedModels = { 'CC605': ['cc605', 'CC605', 'cC605'], 'TC75X': ['TC75X'] },
      selectedModels = ['CC605', 'tc76'];

const models = selectedModels.flatMap(m => mappedModels[m] || []),
      unique = Array.from(new Set([...selectedModels, ...models]));

console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following, :

```js
    var mappedModels = { 'CC605': ['cc605', 'CC605', 'cC605'], 'TC75X': ['TC75X'] };
    
    var selectedModels = ['CC605', 'tc76'];
    
    var  desiredOutput;
    
    function combineModelCases(selectedValue){
    if(mappedModels.hasOwnProperty(selectedValue)){
      desiredOutput = [... new Set([...mappedModels[selectedValue], ...selectedModels])]
      return desiredOutput;
     }
    }

  console.log(combineModelCases('CC605'));
```

here is the working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/wzo4d6uy/2/:

Comment: It's not working. If we add selectedModels.forEach(elm =>{...your code here..} will work.

Comment: No output, blank console

Comment: @SRana  its working you need to call the function and pass value into it to see the output : please check here : https://jsfiddle.net/1q94das5/1/

Comment: I have to pass whole selectedmodel array not  a single item. As i commented earlier you need one more loop on top that to achieve it.